$\mathbb{F}_{11}[x]/(x^2+1)$ and $\mathbb{F}_{11}[y]/(y^2+2y+2)$ are both fields with 121 elements
Below is my attempt to prove that $\mathbb{F}_{11}[x]/(x^2+1)$ and $\mathbb{F}_{11}[y]/(y^2+2y+2)$ are both of order $121$:
Notice that $\mathbb{F}_{11}[x]/(x^2+1)$ are a field with $\{1, x, x^2, x^3,\dots\}$ as basis. The concept of quotient tells us that $x^2+1=0$, which says $x^2=-1$. So the basis is actually $\{1, x, -1, -x, 1, x,\dots\}=\{1, x\}$. Therefore we say $\mathbb{F}_{11}[x]/(x^2+1)=\{a+bx:a,b\in\mathbb{F}_{11}\}$, and it has elements $11\times11=121$, as there are 11 choices for $a$ and $11$ choices for $b$.
The method for $\mathbb{F}_{11}[y]/(y^2+2y+2)$ is similar, but this time we use $\{1, y+1, (y+1)^2,\dots\}$ as basis. Since $y^2+2y+2=(y+1)^2+1=0$, we say $(y+1)^2=-1$ so the basis is indeed $\{1, y+1, -1, -y-1,\dots\}=\{1, y+1\}$. So $\mathbb{F}_{11}[y]/(y^2+2y+2)=\{a+b+by=c+by, c,b\in\mathbb{F}_{11}\}$, which has 121 elements.
Is my idea right?

the basis is actually ${1,x}$

For those new to field theory, I humbly suggest that one write, say, elements of ${F}{11}[x]/(x^2+1)$ as what they exactly are: cosets of $I=(x^2+1)$. Then elements of ${F}{11}[x]/I$ should actually look like $f(x)+I$, and set-theoratically speaking, ${F}{11}[x]/I$ is an extension of $$F'{11}={a+I: a\in F_{11}}.$$ You wrote by introducing $x$ as an "alien element" and adjointing it to $F_{11}$. I think this may confuse yourself.

Also you said ${x^n+I}{n\ge 0}$ is a basis of ${F}{11}[x]/I$ over $F'{11}$. This is incorrect. If we denote $u=x+I$, then ${F}{11}[x]/I=F'{11}(u)$. The irreducible polynomial of $u$ wrt $F'{11}$ is $\psi(X)=X^2+1_{F'{11}}(=X^2+(1+I))$, since $$\psi(u)=u^2+(1+I)=(x+I)^2+(1+I)=(x^2+1)+I=0+I$$ and $\psi$ is irreducible on $F'{11}$ (since no elements of $F'{11}$ is a zero of $\psi$). Then it is a basic fact that ${1{{F}{11}[x]/I},u}={1+I, x+I}$ is a basis of ${F}{11}[x]/I$ over $F'_{11}$.

What @Asigan said!!!! Squared. That. Is a major source of confusion to noobs.

If you allow yourself just a teensy bit of "field theory", then all you have to do is prove that $x^2+1$ and $y^2+2y+2$ are irreducible as polynomials over $\mathbb F_{11}$. Indeed, since replacing $y$ by $y-1$ converts the second poly to the first, you only need to check that one's irreducibility. And then there cannot be a $4$th root of unity in $\mathbb F_{11}$, since the multiplicative group is of order $11-1=10$, which is not divisible by $4$.

Nitpick:  of course there's a fourth root of unity;   just not a primitive one.

Since quotienting an integral domain by a maximal ideal gives you a field, and since both polynomials are irreducible (see the other answer), they are both fields, extensions of $F_{11}$ of degree $2.$
Those fields are the same,  vector spaces of dimension $2$ over the prime subfield,  $F_{11}.$  Thus the order is $11^2=121.$
To correct you,  a basis will have order $2,$ and consist in $\{1,\alpha\},$ where $\alpha $ is a root of either polynomial.
